# Capturing Word application using COM

Tags: com, ms-word

I am trying to capture the name and path for an active Word application using COM components But whenever a dialog box (like save as.. or print etc.) is open, I get a COMException - "The message filter indicated that the application is busy". Is there a way around it for fetching the document details?

Thanks

Comment: Is Word used in an interactive way? Or using automation only? In the latter case you can set the value of `DisplayAlerts` accordingly to prevent most popups. Otherwise you are out of luck and have to wait until the user closes the modal dialog.

Comment: The word is used in an interactive way.
If I cannot fetch the path of the document when the dialog box is open, then may be I have some other way of knowing that a dialog box is open on the last active word window (for which I already captured all the details)? I mean, is there any alternative way, an ID or something to just know that it is the same document as the last one?
Thanks..

Comment: Can it be done using the registry entry for the word application?

Answer (score 0):

What you likely want to do is write an addin for word (Iether VSTO, or by implementing IExtensibility2). Word will signal the addin of all sorts of events (like opening/saving files, etc), and then the addin would signal whatever external app you need to signal, in whatever way you might want for it to signal (Com, DDE, Named pipes, polling, etc). A caution about DisplayAlerts. It doesn't supress ALL alerts, so if you're addin manipulates and controls word, you just have to not do things that can result in a dialog.